# How to solve telegram invalid token due to additional newline character?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I have a project with python-telegram-bot where I'm encountering some error. My develop environment is centos7 and python3.6.8

Below contents is code where the errors occure:

```
import telegram
from telegram.ext import Updater
from telegram.ext import CommandHandler
from telegram.ext import MessageHandler, Filters
from main import *

with open(r"/home/inseo/바탕화면/weather_report/telegram_key.txt","r") as file:
        token = file.readline()


wp = Weather_Report()

updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
dispatcher = updater.dispatcher
```

The file *telegram_api.txt* contains the api key that I was given by telegram_chatbot. This code is executing normally in windows10, but when I'm going to run this code in linux(centos7) errors occure like below:

```
[root@localhost weather_report]# python3 message.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "message.py", line 13, in <module>
    updater = Updater(token=token, use_context=True)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/updater.py", line 290, in __init__
    else arbitrary_callback_data
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/ext/extbot.py", line 103, in __init__
    private_key_password=private_key_password,
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 191, in __init__
    self.token = self._validate_token(token)
  File "/root/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/telegram/bot.py", line 347, in _validate_token
    raise InvalidToken()
telegram.error.InvalidToken: Invalid token
```

I checked that the api key is right, but it doesn't work well. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and fixed it by using `.strip()` on the token string variable in order to get rid of an additional newline character at the end of the file.

See if that helps you fix your problem.

Comment: thanks a lot! thanks to you, i solved this error!!

Comment: Glad I could help, happy coding! :)